# Is it okay to post parodies of songs and poems in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

For fun, I have a couple of times produced something a bit more creative than technical with a Stack Overflow answer. Just recently, I did a parody of "Love Shack" by the B-52's (link in my signature).

I am just wondering if there is anything more I need to do than to just mention the work and artist I am parodying, or if it is better I should avoid full-on parodies.

Comment: I'd be far more worried about this policy: "I don't down vote (except by accident, in which case I will undo it.)"

Comment: The parody is in an answer? It is appropriate for your personal blog, not SO.

Comment: New policy: downvote but don't inhale it.

Comment: Stacks are overplayed. I'm holding out for some Reverend Horton Heap.

Comment: Haiku maybe ok... I don't see long wall of text that most visitors would not be able appreciate (i.e. due to language barrier) or associate with anything (15 years old song is not necessary well known to whole generation of 20-something) as good answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Perhaps a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SOryJvTAGs) would make it easier to relate to?

Comment: what the hell is this/am not good with computer/oscillationing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can actually answer the question clearly and accurately with the parody, I'd say it's entirely acceptable. I'll even upvote it if I think it's really clever. If you do try your hand at one, you should give credit to the original artist to be safe, and besides, there really isn't any reason not to. Even Weird Al gives credit to the artists he parodies, as well as the ones whose songs appear in his polkas.<sup>1</sup>

If the parody doesn't address the question in any way, or it's not essential to the answer, then it's *probably* worth keeping out of the answer if readers find it distracting.

And if it takes up more space in the answer section than the actual answer...

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Al hasn't made a direct parody of Love Shack, but it does appear in one of my favorite polka medleys, Polka Your Eyes Out.</sub>

Comment: I think in Weird Al's case, it *is* strictly necessary that he gives credit. He might not be copying the lyrics, but he is copying everything else. What he doesn't need is permission from the original artist, although he generally seeks this anyway.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Oh, yeah, looks like I got those two mixed up.

Comment: Hmm... interesting point about taking up space. I compressed the format a bit to make it more equitable, the song had many stanzas. I'll pick shorter songs in the future.